# How do I change the default server for nslookup?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, nslookup

So, I have two network cards in my computer on two separate networks. I'd like to have nslookup use slcity server as the default server. However, it automatically chooses sltv. How do I change the default server?

[image: NSLOOKUP]

Comment: "However, it automatically chooses sltv." - Have you specified your DNS nameserver provider in the connection settings?  You have done that for your WIFi connection.  Why are you blocking out internal intranet ip addresses

Comment: To answer your question, you change servers by typing "server <server name or IP address>"   You have two default gateways, that's going to give you problems too.

Comment: @Ramhound - It's just habit to block out stuff. Better safe than sorry. The IP addresses are not important for this though. I will give your option a try and see what happens. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @Larryc - I've tried to nslookup followed by <server name\IP address>. I just need a more permanent option. Is a permanent option even possible?

Comment: Sure. When you start nslookup it tells you the name/IP of the server it will be using for your queries (so long as you don't change that). This is the "default" DNS server that you currently have configured in the properties of your network interface.This includes your IP address, mask, gateway, and your choices for DNS servers, Nslookup just goes there and grabs your first choice. If you haven't specified your choices then it may choose them for you automatically. If you don't like the default DNS server then go to the configuration and enter your choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the DNS server just after the host name or IP address:

```
Nslookup IP_Adress DNS_Server
```

If you enter nslookup prompt then you can specify DNS default server there:

```
C:\Users\Wasif>nslookup
>server 8.8.8.8
```

Now each query in the prompt will use this DNS server.

Comment: That's what I've done and it works. However, I want the change to be permanent and automatic. How can I make the change on a more permanent basis?

Comment: There is no way. The only way that you change your DHCP assigned DNS server to a static one using TCP/IPv4 settings of your connection.

Comment: OK. I appreciate you answering my questions and helping with this. Thank you.